# Result of (int)-2147483648 divided by (int)-1, using different compilers?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, integer

As we all know, the smallest integer is different depending on the compiler, so I have this question: What's the result of `(int)-2147483648` divided by `(int)-1` you get when you use various compilers? For example, VC6.0, VS2010 etc.?

Comment: out of curiosity: why would you try _dividing_? Yes, it's the same in this case, but I wouldn't have ever thought of doing negation with division instead of multiplication.

Comment: Multiplication or division doesn't matter. The result is implementation defined if the result of an arithmetic operation on signed ints isn't representable. An implementation can define the result or raise a signal. (At least in C99, cf §6.3.1.3.) You'll need to look in Microsoft's compiler docs.

Comment: @Mat it is not implementation defined. It is undefined behavior: `INT_MIN / -1` is undefined behavior because of `6.5.5p5` in c99.

Comment: By the way, I cannot understand why this question has been closed. If some people wrongly assume this division is implementation-defined I think the question has to be reopened.

Comment: @ouah: I don't see that spelled out in 6.5.5/5, only division by zero (but I did indeed think that specific case was undefined...). And agree with you, I don't see why this was closed. (There's probably a dup out there though.)

Comment: @Mat sorry 6.5p5, not 6.5.5p5.

Comment: Related question: [Why it is different between -2147483648 and (int)-2147483648](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620753/why-it-is-different-between-2147483648-and-int-2147483648)

Comment: Why do you need to know this? The behavior is undefined, so you should never try in the first place, and compilers are not required to give consistent results.

Comment: On x86/x86_64, you commonly get a floating point exception when you do that.

Answer (score 1):

First let's assume we are in a `32-bit` system with two's complement representation where `INT_MIN` value is the same as `-INT_MAX - 1`.

This expression:

`(int) -2147483648 / (int) -1`

is equivalent to

`(int) -2147483648 / -1`

as `-1` is already of type `int`.

In a `32-bit` two's complement system where `INT_MAX` is `2147483647`, the value `2147483648` is of type `long`<sup>1)</sup> as it cannot be represented in an `int`. The value of `-2147483648` is also of type `long`.

The `long` value `-2147483648` can be represented in an `int`, and the value after the integer conversion of `(int) -2147483648` is `INT_MIN`.

The original expression is then equivalent (under our assumptions) to:

`INT_MIN / -1`

and this expression is equivalent to `INT_MAX + 1` which is not representable in an `int`. Indeed `int` type range goes from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`. The expression is an integer overflow and integer overflow invokes undefined behavior in C.

> (C99, 6.5p5) "If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined."

---

1) We implicitly assume `LONG_MAX` is `> INT_MAX`, otherwise the value `2147483648` is of type `long long`.

Comment: 6.3.1.3(1): "When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged." _Usually_, the value of `(int) -2147483648` is not implementation-defined [beyond the implementation-definedness of integer type sizes and representations] and results in `INT_MIN`. Only if the width of `int` is less than 32 bits, or the representation is not two's complement, or the value with sign-bit 1 and all value bits 0 is a trap representation can it be something else than `-2147483648`.

Comment: @DanielFischer gosh, I missed the point in the second part of my answer. Of course `-2147483648` is representable in an `int` and it is indeed `INT_MIN`, I don't know what I was thinking about. Thank you, I'm editing this.