# Clarification regarding signed and unsigned integers in C language

Tags: c

I have tried following program in C language and the result of the program is:

Output : 0 is printed at last when the `i` is `unsigned int`, when the value of `i` is 0, then the control should not go inside the while loop since I have given `i>0` condition, but 0 is printed, I didn't understand how it is possible.

When the `i` is signed `int`, then 0 is not printed.

Please let me know what is happening in the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   unsigned int i=1;
   int c=1;
   while(i>0)
   {
     i=i*2;         
     c++;
     printf("%d\n",i);          
   }

   printf("%d c value is",c) ;
}
```

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c/14695202#14695202

Comment: Also just before printing zero check the value of `i`.

Comment: Vamsi - **always enable warnings when you compile your code** For example, at a minimum use: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o youroutput yourcode.c` That will show you the problem areas every time :)

Answer (score 5):

Using `%d` with `unsigned int` causes undefined behaviour. To fix your program, change `%d` to `%u` and then the results will make more sense.

When `i` gets to 2<sup>31</sup> (assuming you have 32-bit ints) and you do `i * 2` then the result , which would be 2<sup>32</sup> actually wraps around to `0`, which is why your loop ends. Unsigned integers wrap around like this (technical definition is arithmetic modulo `UINT_MAX+1`).

If `i` is signed int (and you use `%d`) then you cause undefined behaviour when `i * 2` would exceed `INT_MAX`, so anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

You have printed `i` inside `while` after computing `i = i*2;` hence when `i` is `unsigned` and has value `2^31`, the `while` condition is `true` and it is again multiplied by `2`, where it becomes `0` due to integer overflow, which is printed and loop gets over the next time `while(i > 0)` condition is checked.

For `signed int`, the **behavior is undefined** as pointed out by *@Anonymous*.

However here it seems that (you cannot rely on this behavior!!) condition of `while` fails when `i` equals `2^31` because it is treated as negative number now (sign bit is `1`), hence it is not multiplied by `2` and doesn't become `0`.

If you do not want to see `0` output, you can try doing `printf` before `i = i*2` statement.

Comment: The behavior for signed int is undefined.

Comment: Hmm.. right, but here it seems to be happening that way only. Thanks for mentioning that anyways... I have included that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case of **unsigned int:**

supposing `int` takes 4 bytes, the value of i becomes `"1073741824"` for which the binary notation is

```
 "01000000 00000000 00000000 00000000"
```

Multiplying it by two again makes the decimal value `"2147483648"` which the binary notation is

```
"10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000".
```

Again multiplying it by two makes the binary notation as follows

```
"00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000".
```

But as `int` occupies only four bytes, 4 least significant bytes are all filled zero, so the value of i becomes zero.

In case of **signed int:**

Most significant bit is used for indication of negative or positive values. 1 for negative numbers. so it prints negative number further multiplying i by 2. Which makes the while condition fails. as negative number is not greater than zero.

Comment: Nice explanation. Please format it properly, and read @Matt McNabb's answer to know about "undefined behavior" with `signed int`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `while` loop so that `printf` is called first. Also, use `%u` for `unsigned int` instead of `%d`.

```
while(i>0)
{
  printf("%u\n",i);          
  i=i*2;         
  c++;
}
```

With this change you will be printing only the value of `i` that pass the conditional of the `while` statement.