# How can I fix error code C4146 "unary minus operator applied to unsigned type.result still unsigned"?

Tags: c, integer, precision

Data type `int`'s  minimum value is -2,147,483,648.

So, I typed

```
int val = -2147483648;
```

But, it has an error:

```
unary minus operator applied to unsigned type.result still unsigned
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c/14695202

Comment: One way to fix this is to get yourself a standard conforming compiler. Seriously. Since 1999 C imposes that decimal constants are always `signed` types. So your error is an error of your compiler.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: That's true, but it is not necessary a non-conformance issue in this case. In C99 and later the behavior is *undefined* if there's no signed integer type that's wide enough to represent the constant. That "covers" the C89/90 behavior as well: using unsigned type is nothing else than just a specific manifestation of undefined behavior. It can also be seen as a compiler-specific extension that defines the undefined.

Comment: @AnT, it is a conformance issue. For C99, there always is an integer type that is at least 64 bit wide, so the constant here is always a valid integer constant.

Answer (score 13):

`2147483648` is out of `int` range on your platform.

Either use a type with more precision to represent the constant

```
int val = -2147483648L;
// or
int val = -2147483648LL;
```

(depending on which type has more precision than `int` on your platform).

Or resort to the good old `- 1` trick

```
int val = -2147483647 - 1;
```

Comment: he could also use the `INT_MIN` macro from `limits.h` if the goal is to get the lowest possible integer value

Comment: The `-1` trick is nice because it triggers fewer compiler warnings, depending on your compiler and build settings.

Comment: @AnT Hi, by any chance you know any way to remove that warning check ?, it cause an error on my side too, but it's kinda strange as it's with gmp.h ressource's file 6.1.1. (gmp mp)

Answer (score 6):

`-2,147,483,648` is interpreted as negation of `2147483648`. `2147483648` exceed maximum positive integer on your system and is considered as unsigned.

Instead, try

```
-2147483647 - 1
```