# How does C++ integer division work for limit and negative values?

Tags: c++, integer, precision, 16-bit, integer-division

I am facing some strange results with integer division in C++. I am trying to calculate this: **-2147483648 / -1**.

What I get is 3 different results in 3 different scenarios:

```
int foo(int numerator, int denominator) {
    int res = numerator / denominator; // produces SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception interrupt

    cout << res << endl;
}

int main() {
    int res = -2147483648 / -1;
    cout << res << endl;               // prints -2147483648
    cout << -2147483648 / -1 << endl;  // prints 2147483648
    foo(-2147483648, -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the integer division operation produces different results in different situations?

Comment: Worth mentioning that code does not compile on Windows VS-2015 saying `negative integral constant converted to unsigned type ` and `unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned` on all `-2147483648 / -1` lines

Comment: Simple answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29355979/1460794).

Comment: This is how visual studio does it: `#define INT_MIN     (-2147483647 - 1) // minimum (signed) int value`

Comment: @flatmouse if that is the definition it's pretty clear that MSVC does not make use of signed integer overflow UB. Incredible that UB as a practice is so fundamentally anchored on that platform.

Comment: @usr I'm not sure I follow. `2147483647` is DB, `-2147483647` is still ok, and finally `-2147483647 - 1` would still be DB as it would fit? Of course, in the program above overflow is unavoidable as `(-2147483647 - 1) / -1` would still overflow and be UB.

Comment: @flatmouse oh I though you had mistyped and meant `INT_MAX (-2147483648 - 1)`. Why is VC using what you quoted? What's the reason?

Comment: @usr `2147483648` is UB even before the unary `-` is considered. So the VC define gets around the problem by avoiding the `2147483648` literal.

Comment: @flatmouse: A literal 2147483648 does not produce UB. "The type of an integer literal is the ﬁrst of the corresponding list in Table 5 in which its value can be represented." It's guaranteed to fit in `unsigned int`, which isn't in the list so it seems wrong that Visual C++ will choose it.   Also guaranteed to fit in `long long int`, which is why it is not UB.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. `2147483648;` is ok. And so is `auto test{2147483648};`. I am surprised that VS will use an unsigned type, contrary to what is stipulated in the standard. Yet I found that it uses `unsigned long`. I wonder why table 5 lists the unsigned types for binary, octal and hex, but not decimal literals?

Comment: @flatmouse: I guess they erroneously used the list that's applicable for integral promotions, namely "int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int"  Or they used the list intended for binary/octal/hexadecimal literals instead of the one for decimal literals.  As for why the rules are different for binary/octal/hex literals, I believe it's because the programmer is then controlling the length of the literal, in bits.  Actually, I'd like to see `auto x = 0x0000000000000001;` automatically become whatever basic type meets the `int64_least_t` idea

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The literal `-2147483648 / -1` is calculated by your compiler as `2147483648` in a data type that is wide enough to hold that value.

When the literal is printed out directly, it prints the value correctly.

When the literal is stored in `res`, it is cast to an `int`. An `int` appears to be 32 bits wide on your system. The value `2147483648` cannot be represented as a 32 bit signed integer, so the cast causes an overflow. On your system, this overflow results in the value `-2147483648` (likely it's using two's complement).

Finally, when trying to perform the division at runtime (in the `foo` function), the `SIGFPE` exception occurs due to the overflow (because the `int` datatype cannot represent the result).

Note that all of these three options rely on platform dependent behavior :

- the fact that the compiler doesn't generate any errors (or other issues) when the literal calculation overflows and just uses a data type large enough to hold the result
- the fact that the `int` overflow when storing the literal generates that specific value (and no other issues)
- the fact that the `SIGFPE` exception is thrown when overflowing at runtime

Comment: AFAICT integer overflow during compilation is Undefined Behavior; using a larger datatype is one possible behavior but as FirstSTep shows, another behavior is to error out.

Comment: @MSalters : yes, I state as much in the last paragraph.

Comment: Which is also a wrong-ish: every platform has to support a wide enough datatype; `long long int` is certainly wide enough.

Comment: @MSalters : you're right - I'm in the habit of answering questions tagged with just "C++" according to C++03, but since it's been a while since C++11 (and C++14 for that matter) came out, I should get with the times and adjust that habit. I've re-worded that part of my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

```
int res = -2147483648 / -1;
cout << res << endl;               // prints -2147483648
cout << -2147483648 / -1 << endl;  // prints 2147483648
int res = numerator / denominator; // produces SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception interrupt
```

Note there're no negative [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#Notes).

> There are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as -1 apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal, which may involve implicit type conversions.

The literal `2147483648` is larger than the max value of `int`, so its type will be `long` (or `long long`, depends on implementation). Then `-2147483648` 's type is `long`, and the result of calculation (`-2147483648 / -1`) is `long` too.

For the 1st case, the result `2147483648` of type `long` is [implicitly converted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) to `int`, but it's larger than the max value of `int`, the result is implementation-defined. (It seems the result is wrapped around according to the rules of the representation (2's complement) here, so you get the result `-2147483648`.)

For the 2nd case, the result with type `long` is printed out directly, so you get the correct result.

For the 3rd case, you're doing the calculation on two `int`s, and the result can't fit in the result type (i.e. `int`), [signed integer arithmetic operation overflow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows) happened, the behavior is undefined. (Produces SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception interrupt here.)

Comment: `-2147483648` could be `long long`, e.g. on MSVC (which has `LONG_MAX=2147483647`)

Comment: iirc in older versions of C++ it could also be a 32-bit unsigned long (which doesn't actually change the final result, but it does change how you get there).

Comment: @plugwash I don't know much about "older" C++. :) For now, it'll be `long` or `long long` (since C++11), it won't be `unsigned` unless use suffix `u`. The representation is implementation-defined, so `long` might be represented by 32-bit integer.

Comment: @plugwash I found it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#Notes), "In C prior to C99 (but not in C++), unsuffixed decimal values that do not fit in long int are allowed to have the type unsigned long int. "

Comment: Great explanation! This post should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

Your outcome might be `INT_MAX+1`, in other words it probably overflows. That is Undefined Behavior, and anything can happen. For instance, a compiler may reject the code outright.

(A system might have `INT_MAX >= 2147483648`, but then you would expect the same result for your 3 testcases)