# I have a question about implicit type conversions in C

Tags: c

```c
unsigned z  = 0x80000000;
long     z2 = -z;

printf("z  is %x, z  is %u\n", z, z);
printf("z2 is %lx, z2 is %ld\n", z2, z2);
```

Print results are as follows:

```
z  is 80000000, z  is 2147483648 
z2 is 80000000, z2 is 2147483648
```

I want to know what happens in this statement.

```c
long z2 = -z;
```

Comment: Will the type of  -z be raised to long ?

Comment: Using the wrong formatter in printf is undefined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14504148/3966456

Comment: @WeijunZhou yes but it does not answer the question. https://godbolt.org/z/E1naoP16f

Comment: A specific working example does not make undefined behavior okay.

Comment: @DaWang Code that is not defined in a specification means it can behave differently at any time for any reason. You might be lucky and you might not. Don't put your users through that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/29355956/1216776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to extend the snippet to the following:

```c
unsigned z  = 0x80000000;
unsigned z1 = -z;
long     z2 = -z;
int      z3 = -z;

printf( "z  is %x, z  is %u\n",   z,  z  );
printf( "z1 is %x, z1 is %u\n",   z1, z1 );
printf( "z2 is %lx, z2 is %ld\n", z2, z2 );
printf( "z3 is %x, z3 is %d\n",   z3, z3 );
```

```
z  is 80000000, z  is 2147483648
z1 is 80000000, z1 is 2147483648
z2 is 80000000, z2 is 2147483648
z3 is 80000000, z3 is -2147483648
```

`z1` helps explain, and there have been questions about `z3`.

---

**What does `-z` do?**

> [C17 §6.5.3.3 ¶3] The result of the unary- operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

Integer promotion only has an effect for types with a lower rank than `int`, so it's not applicable here. This means that `-z` produces an `unsigned`. So `-z` produces -2,147,483,648 (-2<sup>31</sup>) as an `unsigned`.

**-2<sup>31</sup> as a 32-bit `unsigned`**

> [C17 §6.3.1.3 ¶2] Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the
> range of the new type.

On your system, the maximum value of `unsigned` is 4,294,967,295, so the result of `-z` is -2,147,483,648 + ( 4,294,967,295 + 1 ) * 1 = 2,147,483,648 (2<sup>31</sup>). And this is what we see for `z1`.

**Assigning 2<sup>31</sup> to a 64-bit `long`**

> [C17 §6.3.1.3 ¶1] When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.

Next, we assign 2,147,483,648 to `z2`. On your system, a `long` can represent 2,147,483,648, so that value is assigned to it unchanged. And this is what we see for `z2`.

**Assigning 2<sup>31</sup> to a 32-bit `long` or `int`**

> [C17 §6.3.1.3 ¶3] Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Next, we assign 2,147,483,648 to `z3`. This is implementation-defined behaviour. On your system, it assigns the same byte pattern to the `int` as it would for an `unsigned` (`0x80000000`). And this is what we see for `z3`.

Comment: Isn't it the case that on a system where longs and ints are both 32bit, the line long z2 = -z1; would cause signed integer overflow UB assuming z1 = 0x80000000?

Comment: @Simon Goater, No. "[C17 §6.3.1.3 ¶3] Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." Added to answer (in the form of `int z3 = -z;`). The answer now covers all three integer conversions to signed and unsigned integers. (It doesn't cover extending smaller-ranked types to `int` or `unsigned`, though. And `_Bool` has its own section.)

Comment: @SimonGoater -z produces -2,147,483,648 (-2^32)  isn't correct, 2^32 = 4294967296

Comment: @DaWang Yes, but you probably meant to advise ikegami to correct the answer. We all know a signed 32 bit integer with twos complement representation goes from -2^31 <= x < 2^31. I was pointing out the danger of assigning unsigned -2^31 = unsigned 2^31 to a 32 bit signed integer or long, where 'the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised'.

Comment: The spelled out numbers were correct in the answer, but the shorthands using power notation were wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The unary `-` operator behaves as follows (C17 6.5.3.3):

> The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand. The integer
> promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has the promoted type.

In case of `unsigned`, it is not a small integer type (more info about that here: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)) so it is not subject to integer promotion.

Actually nothing at all happens when we apply `-`. To explain why, we could think of this as a kind of having a conversion from `unsigned` to `unsigned`... (C17 6.3.1.3):

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

The above equation is to be regarded as a pure mathematical one with no particular type. So in your case we get the variable `value 2147483648`, the maximum value of an `unsigned` which is 2<sup>32</sup>-1 and then "one more", +1:

-2147483648 - (2<sup>32</sup>-1 + 1) = 2147483648 .

We are back where we started. It turns out that in case of an `unsigned` variable, the `-` has no effect.

---

In case of `long z2 = -z;`, then notably the `-z` sub-expression has *nothing* to do with the type of the left operand of the assignment operator. It is simply calculated as described above. And then the non-negative value `2147483648` is assigned to the `long`.

- If the `long` is 32 bits, this would be problematic since it can't hold such a large value - we'd get an implementation-defined conversion to a negative number (C17 6.3.1.3):

  > Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

  On a sensible 2's complement system, this very likely results in `-2147483648` however, without any signals getting raised. This is the likely outcome on for example gcc/Windows x86_64 (and the majority of other systems too).
- If the `long` is 64 bits, it can fit the number `2147483648` just fine. This is the likely outcome on for example gcc/Linux x86_64.

---

For portable code, don't use `long` or `unsigned`, but `int64_t` and `uint32_t`.