# Negative integral constant converted to unsigned type

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a simple program, and one of the lines is

```
int num = -2147483648;
```

and I get a "Negative integral constant converted to unsigned type" error.

Even when I do

```
int num = 2147483648 * -1;
```

It is the same thing.

The variable num is an int and not an unsigned int, so what's going on?

Comment: I remember this being asked before ([found it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c)), but it's the unary `-` operator applied to a (positive) integer literal that is too big for `int`.

Comment: You may find [**this sample**](http://ideone.com/YiIUwx) interesting. It directly relates to the link chris posted.