# Is it a good code style to cast `-1` to unsigned int?

Tags: c

Is it a good code style to cast `-1` to unsigned int? For example:

```
#define MAX_UINT8 ((uint8_t) -1)
```

comparing to

```
#define MAX_UINT8 0xff
```

Comment: Casting `-1` to unsigned type is OK but defining `MAX_UINT8` by yourself is bad. You should use `UINT8_MAX` from `stdint.h`.

Comment: You may want to read this link: [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)

Comment: `uint8_t someVariable=0xFF;` is the most clear version for me. The max value of `0xFF` for a 8 bit unsigned int is not going to change.

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to create your own definitions for type limits because C has the [potential for subtleties and strange corner cases when limits are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Style and usefulness**

> Is it a good code style to cast `-1` to unsigned int?

Not when coding the maximum  `uint8_t`.
Use `UINT8_MAX` from `inttypes.h` [@MikeCAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67533765/is-it-a-good-code-style-to-cast-1-to-unsigned-int#comment119367561_67533765)

`#define MAX_UINT8 0xff` is OK for pre-processor operations.  Do not rely on casts with pre-processor math. Thus `#define MAX_UINT8 ((uint8_t) -1)` is less useful (and could lead to unexpected pre-processing) than `#define MAX_UINT8 0xff`

Try

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAX_UINT8 ((uint8_t) -1)

#if MAX_UINT8 < 0
#error "MAX_UINT8 < 0"
#endif
```

---

**Type Differences**

`((uint8_t) -1)` is usually type `unsigned char`.  `uint8_t` is an optional type<sup>1</sup>, yet very commonly implemented.

`0xff` is type `int`.

Using one or the other leads to a difference with `_Generic` and `sizeof`.

---

<sup>1</sup>`uintN_t`

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.
> C17dr § 7.20.1.1 3

Comment: `uint8_t` is only "optional" in the sense that having 8-bit types is optional -- if char is 8-bit then this type must exist.   So it can be a good idea to use it as a way to encode that your program is rejected by implementations without 8-bit char.

Comment: @M.M ... and no padding bits with the signed types represented in twos-complement.