# -32768 not fitting into a 16 bit signed value

Tags: c

I am using PCLint v 9.00h

In my code I have the following (where S16 is a signed 16 bit):

```
S16 temperatureResult = -32768;
```

Which unless my brain has stopped working is the smallest value that can fit into this type

But I am getting a lint error of "Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion of integer to smaller type"

If I change the value to -32767 it works fine.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but Doens't the c99 TC3 say that it is implementation defined about they may serve a + and - value of 0? So if thats the case you would have 1 less negative decimal value.

Comment: What is the reason to use a non-standard type for that? If your compiler is C99 you should have `int16_t` and `INT16_MIN` that would work out of the box.

Comment: @JensGustedt It's a coding standard requirement led by MISRA requirements which hasn't been updated for a while. Don't know if the compiler is C99

Comment: That MISRA rule is quite strange. Gcc (and probably many other compilers) can warn about non-value preserving conversions of constant expressions. The cast hides possible bugs; if the value is changed to, say -32769, where the compiler warning probably would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily "not fit". Quite possibly it fits. (Did you actually check it?)

- If your platform uses 32-bit (or larger) `int`, then all arithmetic expressions are evaluated in 32-bit `int` type and the warning simply tells you that you are converting an `int` value to a smaller type. PCLint simply didn't bother to check whether the actual value fits into the destination type.

  You might be able to suppress this warning with an explicit type cast

  ```
  S16 temperatureResult = (S16) -32768;
  ```
- If your platform uses 16-bit `int`, then a slightly different issue might be involved here. In C language `-32768` is not an atomic constant. `-32768` is actually an expression consisting of an unary `-` operator applied to a positive constant `32768`. `32768` is a positive constant that does not fit into a 16-bit type, for which reason the compiler uses a larger type (32-bit `long int` probably) to represent `32768`. Consequently, `-32768` is evaluated in the domain of a larger type and also ends up as a value of larger type. PCLind decided to warn you about the implicit switch to a larger type. (See [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/187690) for more details.)

  If that's what's happening here, then to avoid the warning you can use an explicit type cast

  ```
  S16 temperatureResult = (S16) -32768;
  ```

  or, alternatively, you can express the initialization as

  ```
  S16 temperatureResult = -32767 - 1;
  ```

  In the latter case the compiler should be able to evaluate the constant expression within the domain of 16-bit `int` type.

Comment: In C all integral literals are of type int or larger, and all integral expressions are of type int or larger. Nothing ever is evaluated as short.

Comment: @n.m.: That is true. (My answer is misleading in that regard. Indeed, if the larger type was used, it wouldn't be `int`. I removed explicit references to `int` from the answer.) However, could it be that the platform actually uses 16-bit `int`? 16-bit `int` is allowed by the language. In that case the issue is that an even larger type was used to evaluate the expression. Unfortunately, the warning message does not mention the exact types.

Comment: +1 good description what is going. But for the solution, any decent compiler should have macros for such constants, `INT_MIN` if this is just the `int` type, or `INT16_MIN`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard only guarantees the range of [-32767,32767] for signed short. Your implementation may extend this a bit, like most implementations do, but PCLint checks for standards compliance.

Comment: That's interesting. Which section of the standard has this in please

Comment: 5.2.4.2 Numerical limits in N1570

Comment: Why is that strange value? Shouldn't the range be [-2^n, 2^n - 1] for n+1 bit values?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, the value with all bits `0` but highest bit `1` may be a trap representation.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc There's life beyond two's complement representation. One's conplement and sign+magnitude were once common.

Comment: of course I knew that there are one's complement and sign magnitude but I always thought that the negative limit is -2^n, forgot about the other formats

Answer (score 3):

First of all: it doesn't have to deal with -32768 by standard:

> 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types

[...]

> — minimum value for an object of type short int
>
> SHRT_MIN -32767 // -(215 - 1)
>
> — maximum value for an object of type short int
>
> SHRT_MAX +32767 // 215 - 1

(I'm looking for the part which makes a enviroment defined note about supporting -32768 anyway)

Got it:

The reason why there is sometimes anyway one more number supported is justified by this paragraph:

> 6.2.6.2 Integer types

[...]

> 2 — For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
>   groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits;
>   there shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as
>   the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are
>   M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M <= N). If the sign bit
>   is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>
> — the sign bit has the value -(2N) (two’s complement);
>
> — the sign bit has the value -(2N - 1) (ones’ complement).
>
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1
>   and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’
>   complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and
>   magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a
>   negative zero.

(All I'm quoting is written in ISO/IEC 9899:TC3)

Answer (score 1):

It comes to mind to try:

> S16 temperatureResult = (S16) 0x8000;
>    // ASSUMES twos complement integers

The explicit cast is because [Rule 10.1](http://www.ristancase.com/html/dac/manual/3.12.02%20MISRA-C%202004%20Rules.html) says

> "The value of an expression of integer type shall not be implicitly
>   converted to a different underlying type if ..."

Make it portable:

> S16 temperatureResult = -32767 - 1;

But anyway, if MISRA requires compatibility with ones complement computers (like some Cray supercomputers), then the guaranteed range of signed 16-bit is only [-32767 ... 32767] so you can't achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Same error and an additional one (Loss of information (initialization) (16 bits to 15 bits))

Comment: @Firedragon if MISRA requires compatibility with ones complement computers, then the guaranteed range of signed 16-bit is only to be [-32767 ... 32767].

Comment: Thanks for the information. It sounds like ones complement then which I didn't know about so have learnt something new today

Comment: This causes implementation-defined behaviour. Whether or not it agrees with MISRA, it's probably something you should avoid given that there is a more portable version.

Comment: @MattMcNabb agreed. It's so hard to write portable code in C. Anyway if the code has to be portable to ones complement computers, then the answer is "no can do."

Comment: @Firedragon there is also sign-magnitude format, not only one and two's complement. And C allows all 3 formats for signed type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952123/representation-of-negative-numbers-in-c