# C++ integer constant's type

Tags: c++, types, long-integer

According to MSDN ([Integer Types - VC2008](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hycyd72d%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)):

> The type for a decimal constant without a suffix is either int, long
>   int, or unsigned long int. The first of these three types in which the
>   constant's value can be represented is the type assigned to the
>   constant.

Running the below code on [Visual C++ 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions):

```
void verify_type(int a){printf("int [%i/%#x]\n", a, a);}
void verify_type(unsigned int a){printf("uint [%u/%#x]\n", a, a);}
void verify_type(long a){printf("long [%li/%#lx]\n", a, a);}
void verify_type(unsigned long a){printf("ulong [%lu/%#lx]\n", a, a);}
void verify_type(long long a){printf("long long [%lli/%#llx]\n", a, a);}
void verify_type(unsigned long long a){printf("unsigned long long [%llu/%#llx]\n", a, a);}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof(int) %i\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(long) %i\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("sizeof(long long) %i\n\n", sizeof(long long));

    verify_type(-2147483647);
    verify_type(-2147483648);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
sizeof(int) 4
sizeof(long) 4
sizeof(long long) 8

int [-2147483647/0x80000001]
ulong [2147483648/0x80000000]  <------ Why ulong?
```

I would expect const `-2147483648` () to be **int**. Why do I get a ulong, not int?

I've been programming for quite a long time and until today I've not noticed that + or - is not part of integer constant. This one hint explained everything.

```
      integer-constant:
              decimal-constant integer-suffix<opt>
              octal-constant integer-suffix<opt>
              hexadecimal-constant integer-suffix<opt>

      decimal-constant:
              nonzero-digit
              decimal-constant digit

      octal-constant:
              0
              octal-constant octal-digit

      hexadecimal-constant:
              0x  hexadecimal-digit
              0X  hexadecimal-digit
              hexadecimal-constant hexadecimal-digit

      nonzero-digit: one of
              1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

      octal-digit: one of
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

      hexadecimal-digit: one of
              0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
              a  b  c  d  e  f
              A  B  C  D  E  F

      integer-suffix:
              unsigned-suffix long-suffix<opt>
              long-suffix unsigned-suffix<opt>

      unsigned-suffix: one of
              u  U

      long-suffix: one of
              l  L
```

Comment: This one bug me. Also I have different results here : http://ideone.com/HyyI3r

Comment: note that many of your `printf` statements cause undefined behaviour. You cannot pass a negative value to `%x` or `%lx`.

Comment: There is no function overload in C, so the code can't compile in C. This is some C++ stuffs.

Comment: @Orace you are using C++11 for those results, however OP is using a 2008 compiler. C++ did not have `long long` prior to C++11, so a compiler extension must be in play. Compiler extensions are supposed to be documented ...

Comment: When represented as 32 bits, the values 2147483648 and -2147483648 have exactly the same value: `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`.  How is the compiler to know which to use?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, in old school C++ ideone give a `ulong`: http://ideone.com/WGlarH also answer are really good for this one.

Comment: @Orace it doesn't say for sure, but presumably that is g++ 4.9.2 running in `--std=gnu89` mode which apparently also has this hybrid of standard integer constant rules, but also a 64-bit int type.

Comment: @MikeofSST that's not an issue here , the question is what the *type* is of the given constant expressions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes. My thinking was that, considering the statement from MSDN in the question, the only way to unabiguously represent 0x80000000 is to use an unsigned long, *if the compiler doesn't know the difference between MSB set and sign bit set*, which it can't if the values are otherwise the same.  (I can't quite get my head round it enough to explain in a half-decent way.)

Comment: @MikeofSST: The compiler has a richer representation than just a 32 bits value. For instance, it also has a type (`unsigned long`). That unambiguously tells the compiler that the MSB is NOT a sign bit. The compiler also has an expression `operator-(unsigned long) unsigned_long_literal(2147483648)`. And no, that unary `operator-` does NOT return a signed long.

Comment: @MSalters According to MSDN [Fundamental Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1(v=vs.90).aspx), `int`, `unsigned int`, `long` and `unsigned long` are all represented by 4 bytes.  Since the negation operator is being used on a compile time constant, why would it not be done before the constant value is generated?  This could result in the unambiguosly incorrect result observed.

Comment: @MikeofSST: MSVC has no choice in this. The behavior is well-defined. As for "4 bytes", that's totally irrelevant. Overloading works on the exact type, not `sizeof(type)`. `void foo(int)` and `void foo(long)`  are distinct functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why it is different between -2147483648 and (int)-2147483648](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620753/why-it-is-different-between-2147483648-and-int-2147483648)

Comment: other duplicates: [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695118/2147483648-0-returns-true-in-c) [large negative integer literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511598/large-negative-integer-literals), [Type of integer literals not int by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108642/type-of-integer-literals-not-int-by-default), [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536389/c-casting-minimum-32-bit-integer-2147483648-to-float-gives-positive-number?rq=1)

Comment: similar problem: [-32768 not fitting into a 16 bit signed value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375337/32768-not-fitting-into-a-16-bit-signed-value?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-2147483648` is not an integer literal.  It is the unary operator `-` applied to the integer literal `2147483648`.  That literal's value does not fit in a `signed int` or `signed long`, so it has type `unsigned long`.  The `-` operator does not change that type.

Answer (score 5):

You are applying the unary `-` operator to the integer literal `2147483648`. The integer literal, being `2^31` is too large to fit in a 32-bit `int`. In modern C++, it *should* have been treated as a `long long`, so your result is surprising.

I believe old C standards (prior to `long long`) allowed interpreting a literal too large for `long` to have type `unsigned long`, which is consistent with what you're seeing. I see the documentation from MSDN you quoted at the top of your post repeats this, so that's surely what's going on here.

Comment: C++ did not have `long long` prior to C++11. I'm sure VS2008 didn't have C++11.  However, MS may have added their own int64 type as an extension and cooked up some way of handling constants.

Comment: The documentation linked by OP is titled "C constants" so perhaps it doesn't apply; however it is consistent with the output he is showing. Perhaps the compiler uses C++03 definition for constants up until 4294967295, and after that, switches to `long long`. Or something.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: IIRC, MSVC treated it the sane way. Any literal which was too big causes UB. One valid and reasonable form of UB is an integer literal having type `__int64`.

Answer (score 5):

First, `-2147483648` is not an integer constant, because `-` is a unary operator, not part of a constant (at least in that context). `2147483648` is an integer constant, and `-2147483648` is an expression involving that constant.

Because `2147483648` is not representable as an `int` or `long int`, but is representable as an `unsigned long int`, it gets the type `unsigned long int`. And the result of applying the unary `-` operator to an `unsigned long int` is itself an `unsigned long int`.